# Getting shares from a company that sells alcohol along with other food items

Tags: halal-haram, business, alcohol

My husband works in an online food ordering company in kuwait. This is absolutely halal food.but last year this company was bought by a German company.now my husband gets his salary from halal company because German company has its own online food delivery.and it includes alcohol also.
The German company has given a big amount of shares of it to my husband.now my question is that should he take thsee shares from them or not?? As they sell alcohol also.is it halal for us to sell these shares in stock exchange and get the money.
Remember both companies have their income from their countries.one is muslim and the other is non muslim ams involved in alcohol.JazakAllah khair!